# About the argmin of a sum of positive functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

**Setup:** Let $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ be two positive functions, and that $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x)$.

**Question:** If
$$
\text{argmin}_x f_1(x) = \text{argmin}_x f_2(x) = v,
$$
then is it true that
$$
\text{argmin}_x f(x)=v?
$$
If it is only true under certain condition(s), then may I know what those condition(s) are? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean $v$ instead of $z$?

Comment: Well, $f_1(v) \le f_1(x) \forall x$, and the same for $f_2$. Can you prove it from there?

Comment: Yes typo, I've fixed the question.

Comment: Yes, then $f_1(v)+f_2(v)\leq f(x)$, and hence, $v$ is the argmin of $f(x)$.

Comment: In general, it's always true that $\operatorname{argmin} (f+g)\supseteq (\operatorname{argmin} f)\cap(\operatorname{argmin} g)$